# Widening conversions e option strict on

Tags: vb.net, tipagem, conversão-de-tipo

Estou aprendendo sobre conversões e lendo [esse artigo](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/311329/option-explicit-and-option-strict-in-visual-basic-net-and-in-visual-ba):

> Widening Conversions (não sei o termo em português)
>
> ```
>   The following conversions may lose precision: 
>
>        Integer to Single
>
>        Long to Single or Double
>
>        Decimal to Single or Double
>
>   However, these conversions do not lose information or magnitude.
>
>
>  "As seguintes conversões podem perder precisão:
>
>       Inteiro para Single
>
>       Long para Single ou Double
>
>       Decimal para Single ou Double
>
>   Contudo, essas conversões não causam perda de informação ou magnitude"
> ```

Eu não entendi o que isso quer dizer. Se eu por exemplo tivesse um inteiro de valor 2 e tentasse converter para single, de que forma essa perda de precisão aconteceria?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 2):

Vou pegar a **terceira conversão** da sua pergunta como exemplo.

- Uma variável decimal possui a precisão de **28 ou 29 dígitos**.
- Já uma variável do tipo double possui a precisão de **15 ou 16 dígitos**.

Variáveis do tipo decimal são altamente recomendadas quando se trata de dados que envolvam **finanças**.

**Exemplo:** Você é dono de uma empresa que faz festa de aniversários. Você usa uma variável decimal para armazenar o **preço em dólar de um pirulito** que pretende comprar para colocar nas festas que sua empresa organiza. Você por algum motivo decide converter esse valor da unidade do pirulito para uma variável do tipo double.

No exemplo você decide comprar 10000000 (dez milhões) de pirulitos, **separando EXATAMENTE o valor da quantia em dinheiro para a compra**, baseado na multiplicação do valor da variável double vezes 10000000 (dez milhões).

Com essa conversão certamente **vai faltar ou sobrar dinheiro** (se houver ou não aproximação da última casa decimal), pois a precisão do valor foi perdida no valor que você encontrou, mas na hora da compra o vendedor vai utilizar o valor mais preciso (decimal).

Ainda mais se por algum motivo você fizer essa compra em outra moeda. A conversão para o real já iria ter uma diferença.

No exemplo que você falou, de ter uma variável inteira de valor 2 e a convertesse para para uma single, não teria problema algum, **pois esse é um valor cuja precisão é minúscula, que tanto uma inteira quanto uma variável single englobam**.

Sobre a perda de magnitude ou informação, veja um exemplo onde você tem 3 variáveis (A, B e C):

- A = variável do tipo decimal
- B = variável do tipo double que recebe valor de A
- C = variável do tipo decimal que recebe valor de B

**"Em código":**

```
A = valor qualquer
B = A
C = B
```

C teria exatamente o mesmo valor de A, mesmo tendo sido feita uma conversão para B.

Links que me ajudaram a responder sua pergunta:

http://www.macoratti.net/12/12/c_num1.htm

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/f91fc4dd-47f3-4596-a94f-9c93d8bddc99/capacidade-de-variveis?forum=vsvbasicpt

https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-csharp-orientacao-objetos/variaveis-e-tipos-primitivos/#operaes-com-variveis

http://excelevba.com.br/variaveis-no-vba/

Answer (score 2):

Este exemplo não teria perda, esta conversão é a chamada *widening*, então ele está pegando algo estreito e tornando mais largo. Você pega algo que existe no outro tipo.

Precisão é detalhamento, quanto mais preciso mais próximo do número que necessita você tem. Precisão não é exatidão, esta característica exige que o número seja exato o que precisa.

Perda de informação ou magnitude é você ter um valor 1000 por exemplo e por alguma razão isso virar 100, ou -200 virar 200.

O inteiro permite números entre -2,147,483,648 e 2,147,483,647. Isto porque todos esses números cabem em *slots* de 2 elevado a 32, portanto temos pouco mais de 4 bilhões de *slots*. De onde vem esse número? O 2 são os valores possíveis do sistema de numeração binário, e 32 é a quantidade de bits que um número inteiro tem (4 bytes).

Um `Single` tem também 32 bits, portanto dá para imaginar que pelo fato dele ter uma parte decimal ele não pode ter todos esses mais de 4 bilhões de inteiros. Não entenda errado, ele pode ir até além desses limites de 2 bilhões positivos e negativos, mas ele não consegue representar todos os inteiros possíveis. Ele pula alguns. Ele faz isso porque não depende de ser preciso, você pode trabalhar com um número aproximado e está tudo bem. Ele tem uma forma complicada para a maioria das pessoas entender de quais são os números possíveis, e quais são depende de alguns fatores do número, só ocorre em números muito grandes.

Em alguns casos ele pode ser que você não consiga representar o número 3, mas ficaria com 3.0000000000002 (só um exemplo, não estou pegando um número real que aconteceria isto). Esse número é quase 3, mas não é 3. Por isso que [não pode usar este tipo para valores monetários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101). Em certos problemas quase 3 está bom e serve ao propósito. Note que em números pequenos nunca haverá perda, todos os inteiros podem ser representados. Só com números muito grandes ele teria que usar artifícios que não daria para representar o número exato.

O `Double` tem 64 bits então ele consegue representar todos os mais de 4 bilhões de inteiros possíveis, e mais um monte de outros, além de poder representar também parte decimal. Por isso ele nunca tem perda nesse tipo quando se converte de `Integer`.

Mas um `Long` para `Double` pode ter perda porque este tipo também tem 64 bits e pode comportar muito mais inteiros, então claro que outro tipo que pode ter parte inteira e parte decimal do mesmo tamanho na memória não tem como representar tudo.

O `Decimal` tem 128 bits, então é pior ainda.

Comment: Poderia me dizer uma situação em que uma conversão de Inteiro para Single teria perda de precisão?

Comment: Conforme eu coloquei na resposta em número muito grandes.